# How to inject "application_id" in some test endpoint "/v1/random-session/{id}/submit"?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am reading endpoints from xls file for testPlan creation and i have to do series of test on various endpoints to check the functionality. But the application_id is generated only after the first request and then it is available by the static util class. How should i structure end points in my xls which have the application_id generated at the session start? What is the best java API that i can use to inject application_id in place of {id} in the end-point?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to use MessageFormat such as :

```
    Object[] testArgs = {"coco"};
    final String myformat = java.text.MessageFormat.format( "hello {0}", testArgs );
```

Comment: Why is my answer tagged as "unusefull" ?